# Find index of closest value to given value in numpy array. Restricted to outer indexes

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array called directions as follows:

```
[[ 315.    326.31  341.57    0.     18.43   33.69   45.  ]
[ 303.69  315.    333.43    0.     26.57   45.     56.31]
[ 288.43  296.57  315.      0.     45.     63.43   71.57]
[ 270.    270.    270.      0.     90.     90.     90.  ]
[ 251.57  243.43  225.    180.    135.    116.57  108.43]
[ 236.31  225.    206.57  180.    153.43  135.    123.69]
[ 225.    213.69  198.43  180.    161.57  146.31  135.  ]]
```

I want to search the array and find the index of the closest value from a given value (e.g. 45). This is what I do so far:

```
x = np.abs(directions-45)
idx = np.where(x == x.min())
```

This works, in as much as it returns all the indexes that meet this criteria. However, I want to restrict the returned indexes to only those on the outer edge of the array, i.e. the top and bottom rows, and the far right and left columns. If a number is closer to the given value that is not in the outer edges, then I would like to extend the search until the closest number on the outer edge is found.

Thanks!

Comment: Can we assume a square shaped array?

Comment: `" If a number is closer to the given value that is not in the outer edges"` - closer being a relatively term without any tolerance on the closeness, how would you know that? For example, let's say `directions[0,-1]` is say `90` i.e. not `45`, so what do we say to whether we have found the match in the outer edge or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the line

```
x[1:-1, 1:-1] = x.max()+1
```

before you find `idx`, to overwrite the values in the center with a value higher than any edge value.

```
x = np.abs(directions-45)
x[1:-1, 1:-1] = x.max()+1
idx = np.where(x == x.min())
idx
Out[25]: (array([0], dtype=int64), array([6], dtype=int64))
```